# In Bash, how to strip out all numbers in the file names in a directory while leaving the file extension intact

Tags: macos, bash

I have files in a directory like this:

```
asdfs54345gsdf.pdf
gsdf6456wer.pdf
oirt4534724wefd.pdf
```

I want to rename all the files to just the numbers + .pdf so the above files would be renamed to:

```
54345.pdf
6456.pdf
4534724.pdf
```

The best would be a native Bash command or script (OSX 10.6.8)

Some clues I picked up include

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' input.txt 
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' input.txt > output.txt 
sed -i 's/[^0-9]*//g' input.txt 
echo ${A//[0-9]/} rename 's/[0-9] //' *.pdf
```

Comment: This is site is about helping with programming problems, not 'give me the code'. Best to edit your question to show us what you have tried so far. Good luck.

Comment: You should look into regular expressions, the commands `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: @shellter,  sorry yes, I failed to mention that I spent two hours googling regular expressions etc to no avail.  Some clues I picked up include sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' input.txt
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' input.txt > output.txt
sed -i 's/[^0-9]*//g' input.txt


echo ${A//[0-9]/}

rename 's/[0-9] //' *.pdf

Comment: I've edited your question to include what you put in a comment. It is much easier to read there. Note that for code to appear in a question, you need to indent each line with 4 spaces AND have a blank line before and after the code block. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sould do it:

```
for f in *.pdf 
do 
   mv "$f" "${f//[^0-9]/}.pdf"
done
```

but you better try before:

```
for f in *.pdf 
do 
   echo mv "$f" "${f//[^0-9]/}.pdf"
done
```

Note, that abc4.pdf and zzz4.pdf will both be renamed to 4.pdf. So maybe you use `mv -i` instead of just mv.

#### updte: explaining:

I guess the fist part is clear; `*.pdf` is called globbing, and matches all files, ending with .pdf. `for f in ...` just iterates over them, setting f to one of them each time.

```
for f in *.pdf 
do 
   mv "$f" "${f//[^0-9]/}.pdf"
done
```

I guess

```
mv source target
```

is clear as well. If a file is named "Unnamed File1", you need to mask it with quotes, because else mv will read

```
mv Unnamed File1 1.pdf
```

which means, it has multiple files to move, Unnamed and File1, and will interpret 1.pdf to be a directory to move both files to.

Okay, I guess the real issue is here:

```
"${f//[^0-9]/}.pdf"
```

There is an outer glueing of characters. Let be

```
 foo=bar
```

some variable assignment Then

```
 $foo
 ${foo}
 "$foo"
 "${foo}"
```

are four legitimate ways to refer to them. The last two used to mask blanks and such, so this is in some cases no difference, in some cases it is.

If we glue something together

```
 $foo4
 ${foo}4
 "$foo"4
 "${foo}"4
```

the first form will not work - the shell will look for a variable foo4. All other 3 expressions refer to bar4 - first $foo is interpreted as bar, and then 4 is appended. For some characters the masking is not needed:

```
 $foo/fool
 ${foo}/fool
 "$foo"/fool
 "${foo}"/fool
```

will all be interpreted in the same way. So whatever "${f//[^0-9]/}" is, "${f//[^0-9]/}.pdf" is ".pdf" appended to it.

We approach the kernel of all mysterias:

```
${f//[^0-9]/}
```

This is a substitution expression of the form

```
${variable//pattern/replacement}
```

- variable is $f (we can omit the $ inside the braces here) is said $f from above. That was easy!
- replacement is empty - that was even more easy.
- But [^0-9] is something really complicated, isn't it?

-

```
[0-9]
```

is just the group of all digits from 0 to 9, other groups could be:

```
[0-4] digits below 5
[02468] even digits
[a-z] lower case letters 
[a-zA-Z] all (common latin) characters 
[;:,/] semicolon, colon, comma, slash
```

The Caret ^ in front as first character is the negation of the group:

```
[^0-9]
```

means everything except 0 to 9 (including dot, comma, colon, ...) is in the group. Together:

```
 ${f//[^0-9]/}
```

remove all non-digits from $f, and

```
"${f//[^0-9]/}.pdf"
```

append .pdf - the whole thing masked.

```
 ${v//p/r}
```

and its friends (there are many useful) are explained in `man bash` in the chapter `Parameter Expansion`. For the group I don't have a source for further reading at hand.

Comment: works great, thank you.  Now I need to figure out how that works.  I want to learn this rather than just copy and pasting code.  :)

Comment: @nube: I updated my answer to explain every part of the command.